# Graph to show the variation against speed

Tags: physics, kinematics

I have the question "A speeding motorist is travelling at a constant speed of 40 m/s on a motorway. He passes a stationary police car, which immediately accelerates at a rate of 2.5 ms^-2 to a constant speed of 50 m/s. (Assume negligible resistive forces).

Sketch a graph to show the variation of speed against time for both vehicles. "

Is my graph correct ? With B being the police car and A the motorist.

[image]

Comment: There is no reason to neglect resistive forces when the vehicles are equipped with engines that allow them to go at constant speed anyway

Comment: Yes that is true :)

Comment: I would annotate that the elbow of $B$ curve is at $t=20s$.

Comment: Why is t equal to 20s ? Thanks